# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una llamada a todos los productos de woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando un plugin de wordpress y me gustaría llamar los productos de Woocomerce, sin embargo he tenido problemas ya que no conozco de donde obtener los productos y sus detalles.

`$sql = "SELECT post_name FROM wpva_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' ";`

Hice algo así para obtener solo en nombre, pero me gustaría que en una sola consulta pueda traer todo.

O si hay una función especial.

Los datos que me gustaría obtener son Id del producto, su nombre, SKU, imagen, categorías, descripción y descripción corta,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo no te recomendaría usar una consulta directa a la BBDD ya que puede ser peligroso en cuanto a la seguridad de la misma, para ello yo te recomendaría utilizar WP_Query que sirve precisamente para hacer consultas a la misma BBDD pero con mayor seguridad.

Para sacar todos los productos sería algo así:

```
    global $wp_query;    
    $args = array( 'post_type'  => 'product',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'nopaging' => true
                    );
   $the_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $post = $the_query->next_post();
            setup_postdata($post);

            //SACAR INFORMACIÓN DE LA VARIABLE $POST

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
   endif;
```

Comment: Gracias, fue una excelente respuesta